# JButton not executing code properly

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to add a sliding menu to my java project. I found that the code added to the actionPerformed method of the button worked on its own, however, when it was attached to the button, it no longer simulated the animation, but rather waited out the time followed by setting the location of the frame to the final position (panel no longer slides). Any suggestions?

```
btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                    MainActivity.menu.setLocation(MainActivity.menu.getX()+2, MainActivity.menu.getY());
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the "why" and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible "how"

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083355/jpanel-setlocation/19083537#19083537)